# How so I fix a loose Kwikset deadbolt faceplate?

Tags: doors, lock

We have a kwikset deadbolt on our main door and the faceplate has come loose.  There are no visible screws on either side of the door, so I am assuming they are under the brass plate on the inside of the door.  I can't seem to get the plate off though.  There is a little rectangle on the bottom of the plate, but it doesn't seem to help pop off the plate.  The locking handle seems too close for the plate to be allowed to moved enough to reach screws anyway.  Does anyone know how to get the plate off?

Answer (score 2):

The Kwikset locks I've replaced had screws on the deadbolt plate, but I've heard that others have a 'snap-on' plate that can be removed with a flathead screwdriver. This [forum post](http://www.fixya.com/support/t1584737-loose_kwikset_chelsea_deadbolt) seems to concern a case similar to yours.

Comment: Yup, gently work a flat head screw driver around the plate to loosen it (especially if there is paint holding it on) and then with your fingers try and turn it counter-clockwise.  It should pop off at this point.

Answer (score 1):

At the very bottom of the inside plate, you may find a tab that you push in with a flathead screwdriver. Take off the inside handle first. Mine needed a small Allan key for this. When you compress the tab pull forward on the plate. It should pop off. You can then tighten the screws. You might also want to give a squirt of WD 40 on both the inside of the handle and the deadbolt. I also checked the deadbolt for wear. If it is rubbing on something you might want to correct that while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to remove the interior "locking handle" first. That will permit you to remove the cover plate and expose the screws.

To release that handle, look for either a setscrew you can loosen, or a slot or hole where you can insert a probe to depress a spring catch.